# Поиск ближайшего по величине числа в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, поиск

Требуется найти ближайшее заданное число в некотором списке на Python 3. Есть ли какой-то встроенный модуль для таких целей? Или какой алгоритм стоит для этого выбрать?

Answer (score 11):

```
l = [5, 78, 45, 12, 56, 9999]

def nearest(lst, target):
  return min(lst, key=lambda x: abs(x-target))

print(nearest(l, 52))
```

Comment: Понимаю, что вам могла не понравиться моя правка, но считаю что моя правка сделала ответ лучше. [Рекомендуется 4 пробела под отступ](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), [добавление пробела до и после арифметического оператора](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), а также, я считаю, что примеры данных и функции, что с ними работают нужно отделять, поэтому и перенес функцию выше. Плюс, больше примеров использования с наглядным результатом хуже не сделали бы -- сразу было бы видно, что будет получено